# Difficulty in Reading Content from Uploaded JSON File Using Filament FileUpload in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

I am currently working on a Laravel project where I have a resource with a button for importing files. The files to be imported are JSON files. When the import button is pressed, a modal containing a file upload form is displayed. However, I'm facing challenges in initially displaying the contents of the uploaded JSON file before storing it in the database.

Here is the code snippet for the file upload in my Filament resource:

```php
Action::make('attachment')
    ->label('Attachment')
    ->form([
        FileUpload::make('attachment')
    ]);
```

The sample JSON file that I am attempting to import is as follows:

```json
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          // ... (coordinate data)
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to know how to read the contents of the uploaded JSON file, particularly the "coordinates" data, and display them. This will allow me to perform any necessary processing before saving the data to the database.

Any guidance, code examples, or best practices in handling JSON file uploads using Filament would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: You have access to the JSON data right, because it would be as easy as doing `$jsonArray = json_decode({YOUR_FILE});` and then something like `$coords = $jsonArray['features']['geometry']['coordinates'];`

Comment: @geertjanknapen but how to access the json data from FileUpload filament ?

Comment: Well you are probably saving it to a Laravel disk with a filename, so just get the file from the disk (storage) by its filename?